# React "return" unexpected token when using babelify

Tags: reactjs, npm, jsx, babeljs

I have some simple react code as I'm just getting started learning and I think my dev environment may be messed up.  Here's my code (which comes straight from the reactjs tutorial https://reactjs.org/docs/components-and-props.html ):

--package.json:

```
    {
        "author": "Damien Bell",
        "main": "main.js",
        "name": "Learning",
        "version": "0.0.1",
        "dependencies": {
            "babel-core": "^6.26.0",
            "react": "^16.2.0",
            "react-dom": "16.2.0",
            "react-router": "4.2.0"
        },
        "devDependencies": {
            "babelify": "^8.0.0",
            "browserify": "^16.1.0",
            "watchify": "^3.10.0"
        },
        "scripts": {
            "start": "browserify -t babelify --outfile ./App.js reactive.jsx"
        }
    }
```

--reactive.jsx

```
    import React from "react";
    import ReactDOM from "react-dom";

    class Welcome extends React.Component {
        render() {
        return <h1>Hello, {this.props.name}</h1>;
        }
    }


    ReactDOM.render(<Welcome />, document.getElementById("app") );
```

On running "npm start" I get the following error:

```
 > browserify -t babelify --outfile ./App.js reactive.jsx

 SyntaxError: c:/Electron/reactive.jsx: Unexpected token (6:10)
   4 | class Welcome extends React.Component {
   5 |   render() {
 > 6 |     return <h1>Hello, {this.props.name}</h1>;
     |            ^
   7 |   }
   8 |   }
   9 |
```

---

Figured it out, apparently babelify doesn't natively understand that you're going to try to use jsx, and you need to specify that.  There's also a weird thing where if you try to pass that in as an argument as mentioned in the answer below, you can get an error saying "'import' and 'export' may appear only with 'sourceType: module'"

I got around this by creating a .babelrc file and changing my package.json accordingly:

.babelrc

```
    {
    "plugins": [ "transform-class-properties", "transform-decorators-legacy" ],
    "presets": ["es2015", "react", "stage-0"]
    }
```

package.json

```
    "browserify": {
        "transform": [
            [
                "babelify"
            ]
        ]
    },
    "dependencies": {
        "babel-core": "^6.26.0",
        "react": "^16.2.0",
        "react-dom": "16.2.0",
        "react-router": "4.2.0"
    },
    "devDependencies": {
        "babel-plugin-transform-class-properties": "^6.24.1",
        "babel-plugin-transform-decorators-legacy": "^1.3.4",
        "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.24.1",
        "babel-preset-react": "^6.24.1",
        "babel-preset-stage-0": "^6.24.1",
        "babel-preset-env": "^1.6.1",
        "babelify": "^8.0.0",
        "browserify": "^16.1.0",
        "watchify": "^3.10.0"
    },
    "scripts": {
        "start": "browserify -t babelify --outfile ./App.js reactive.jsx && electron ."
    }
```

Comment: can you please show `webpack.config.js` and `.babelrc`

Comment: @Aaqib -- Didn't make either, as I didn't know that was a requirement.

Comment: are you using `create-react-app`?

Comment: Nope, I roughly followed https://babeljs.io/docs/setup/#installation for babelify

Comment: You should create `.babelrc` and install react preset to compile jsx

Comment: @BoyWithSilverWings -- I just pull everything in via npm-i and react is on my dependencies, how would I specify that via package?

Comment: `npm install --save-dev babel-preset-env babel-preset-react`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This error happens because, in your current configuration, `babelify` doesn't understand React's JSX syntax. To fix this, install `babel-preset-react` via npm and change your `start` script to include a React environment:

```
...
"start":"browserify -t 'babelify --presets react' --outfile ./App.js reactive.jsx"
...
```

Comment: Concretely the package OP needs is `babel-plugin-transform-react-jsx`: https://babeljs.io/docs/plugins/transform-react-jsx/. It is included in the `babel-preset-react`.

Comment: I don't know what's happening here, but I'm still seeing the same thing with this command ... https://hastebin.com/gazazujoko.json

Comment: You need single quotes around `babelify --presets react` to pass it as a single argument to browserify.

Comment: This was quite close to the answer in my case.  I'll change my question to show how I got there.